# Exponential Growth of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, exponential-function

Let $f,g: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow [0,+\infty[$ be nondecreasing functions. Then we say that the function $f$ **dominates** the function $g$ if there are positive integers $A,B$ and $C$ such that $$Af(Br)\geqslant g(r)$$ for every $r\geqslant C$.

Let $h: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow [0,+\infty[$ be a nondecreasing function. Then $h$ dominates the exponential function if and only if $$\limsup_{x \longrightarrow +\infty} \frac{\log h(r)}{r}>0$$

The questions are:

1. If a function $T$ dominates the exponential function, does not the function $T$ have exponential growth (since the exponential function dominates $T$) so they are equivalent under the mutual dominance?
2. Is there any function that strictly dominates the exponential function (the function dominates the exponential function but the exponential function does not dominate it)?

Comment: 2. $e^{r^2}$ would do.

Comment: @amsmath it strictly dominates the exponential function?

Comment: Yes, obviously. Let $g(r) = e^{r^2}$ and assume that the exponential function $f(r) = e^r$ dominates $g$. Then there exist integers $A,B,C$ such that $Af(Br)\ge g(r)$ and hence $Ae^{Br}\ge e^{r^2}$ for $r\ge C$. If $A = e^a$, then this is equivalent to $a+Br\ge r^2$ for $r\ge C$, which is clearly a contradiction.